# Angular 10 click event propagation

Tags: javascript, html, angular, events, dom-events

I want to manually modify the value of an input checkbox by clicking everywhere on its html parent.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div (click)="onChange($event)" class="option" *ngFor = "let option of answerForm.options">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{answerForm.type}}{{answerForm.id}}" value="{{option}}">
    <label>{{option}}</label>
</div>
```

Here is my typescript:

```
onChange($event): void {
    if ($event.target !== $event.currentTarget) {return;}
    $event.target.children[0].checked = !$event.target.children[0].checked;
}
```

The event works correctly when I click on the div.
When I click on the label, the event is trigger, with the label as a target and doesn't pass the condition as expected.  
I expect the event propagation to automatically trigger the event for the parent, but it doesn't. It seems to be the default behavior of Angular but I am not really sure.

Do you have any solution to only trigger the click event for the div wherever the click is made on it ?

Comment: If you're trying to prevent the default behavior, you could try putting '$event.preventDefault()' as the first line of the onChange method.

Answer (score 2):

Since what you are trying to do is always have the parent as the target of the click event instead of the children. You can use the css property `pointer-events` setted to `none`.

In the following way,

```
<div (click)="onChange($event)" class="option" *ngFor = "let option of answerForm.options">
<input type="checkbox" style="pointer-events: none" name="{{answerForm.type}}{{answerForm.id}}" value="{{option}}">
<label style="pointer-events: none">{{option}}</label>
```

**Why does this work?**

As it's said in Mozilla MDN Web Docs, the pointer events sets under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of pointer events. In the case of the value `none`,

> The element is never the target of pointer events; however, pointer events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, pointer events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases

For more information you can visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, your answer is only contains about code and it needed to add more detail in it. for more information about  good answers in StackOverflow please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .

Comment: Is it better this way? Thanks so much for the feedback.

Comment: yes it is, I voted up your answer because it has a good quality ,thanks for your cooperation, good luck ...

Comment: Thank you ! It works for me :). I didn't knew this css property

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, You can prevent any triggered events with css, for example add input and label style - pointer-events : none

```
<div (click)="onChange($event)" class="option" *ngFor = "let option of answerForm.options">
    <input type="checkbox" style="opinter-events: none" name="{{answerForm.type}}{{answerForm.id}}" value="{{option}}">
    <label style="opinter-events: none">{{option}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Same thing that I said to Philip, this is the solution I choose but you have a miss spelling of pointer-events

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<input type="checkbox" name="{{answerForm.type}}{{answerForm.id}}" value="{{option}}" style="pointer-events: none">`

Comment: This is what i decided to use, on input and label. You should edit you answer to write pointer-events instead of opinter-events. 
But thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import {Directive, HostListener} from "@angular/core";
    
@Directive({
    selector: "[click-stop-propagation]"
})
export class ClickStopPropagation
{
    @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
    public onClick(event: any): void
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Then just add it to the element you want it on:

```
<div click-stop-propagation>Stop Propagation</div>
```